# Problematically clicking on element in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, dom-events

I'm using `event.preventDefault()` for all elements on the page with Jquery like this:

```
$('*').on('click', function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now I would like to trigger a click event using the the context menu on right click. So basically I would right click the mouse and a context menu would open and from that menu I would choose to trigger the click. In Jquery this is simple I would do this in my function related to the context menu:

```
$(this).click();
```

The `this` part would get the selector and the `click` part would trigger the click, of course with `return true` to lift the preventDefault. The problem is that I can't use Jquery in the latter, I have to use plain Javascript. What is the equivalent of  `$(this).click();` in plain Javascript? (without attaching click handlers on the elements themselves that is)

Comment: @meagar I can't use `document.getElementById` as in the "duplicate" because I don't know what I'm clicking on upfront...That is basically the point of my question

Comment: @meagar Care to explain yourself...?

Comment: You can use document.addEventListener, I wrote a small demo here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gn0r2ej/1/)

Comment: And as you said I agree this is not the exact same thing as the "duplicate", trigger must have a target and in this case we want an event listener

Comment: @ClemSndr I don't get it..How should I use this when programmatically clicking on various elements?

Comment: The code I gave you is a replacement for `$('*').on('click', function(e) {`, then you have to wrap you code inside it and use e.target.id to act on the element wich has been clicked

Comment: @ClemSndr Ah I get it thank you very much, and thanks again for elaborating on it:)